# Size of System.Drawing.Image has been increased after Save

Tags: image, asp.net-core

Good day sir,

I got a question about my file **test.png**, **8mb.**

After save, size of this file has been increased, **24mb.**

Any solution to keep as original, **8mb**

`var imagePath = @"C:\Users\test.png";`

`var savePath = @"C:\Users\result.png";`

`Image image = Image.FromFile(imagePath);`

`image.Save(savePath);`

Answer (score 0):

Because you have defualt  Quality,ColorDepth,Compression, and etc parametrs in Image class for save new file and it is different with old file. you can set EncoderParameters on save Methed.

```
   var imagePath = @"C:\temp\test.png";
   var savePath = @"C:\temp\result.png";

   Image image = Image.FromFile(imagePath);

   ImageCodecInfo pngCodec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().FirstOrDefault(x => x.MimeType == "image/png");


   EncoderParameters encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
   encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality,100);

   image.Save(savePath, pngCodec, encoderParameters);
```